# Unity ParticleSystem collidesWith

Tags: unity-game-engine, particle-system

I am trying to change collidesWith paramater of an particle system inside of a script but i am getting this error:

> Error CS1612  Cannot modify the return
>   value of 'ParticleSystem.collision'
>   because it is not a variable

**My Code:**

```
GameObject ammo; //Game object with ParticleSystem on it
public LayerMask desiredLayers; 

private void Start()
{
    ammo.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>().collision.collidesWith = desiredLayers;
}
```

Now my question is what is the correct way to change the layers of a particle system collide with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay i figure it out, apparently ParticleSystem is a property.

And Unity have something special for ParticleSystem which uses Pointers so following code solved my problem:

```
var collidesWith = ammo.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>().collision.collidesWith;
collidesWith = desiredLayers;
```